# Laravel getRelations() returns blank

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

> I'm trying to query a relationship for use with an accessor with
>   getNameAttribute this is my code

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Conference extends Model{

    public function getNameAttribute() {
        return $this->getRelation('event')->name;
    }

    public function event() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Event');
    }

    public function speakers() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Speaker');
    }
}
```

But it's returnin nothing.. Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time you are requesting the relation `event`, this relation is not yet loaded, that's why you get empty value. If you want to access the `event` relation just do this `$this->event` it will load it, so you can access it's properties:

```
public function getNameAttribute() {
    return $this->event->name;
}
```

`getRelation` method will return to you a relation, if it was already loaded in the model, it will not trigger the loading.

Comment: Oh wow that was easy, How can it have access to the event? Via the eloquent ORM?

Comment: @Notflip yes, it is triggering the Eloquent's magic  `__get` method.  You can check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) it has a lot of cool tricks and tips.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `getRelationValue` instead.

```
public function getNameAttribute() {
    return $this->getRelationValue('event')->name;
}
```

This method will load the relation if it isn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

getRelationValue is a great way to bring in a related model that you're going to do an aggregate function on. Counts can use withCount but for sums and averages the getRelationValue works better with eager loading than making a direct call to the related model.